# Fade out on scrolling page - background div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Never used jquery and I am trying to get my background image to fade out when I scroll.

I have tried to use different jquery code, nothing seems to be working.

Html

```
<div id="background" class="background-div">
<div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown">
   <a href="index.html">Home</a>
   <a href="about.html">About</a>
   <a href="contact-php.html">Contact</a>
 </div>
 <div class="contact-title">
   <h2>Get in touch with us</h2>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
.background-div{
  background: url('../pics/pic-12.jpg')no-repeat 75%;
  top: 0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
}
```

JS/Jquery

/*Fade out on scroll*/

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(this).scrollTop() > 250) {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1250)
       $('#background').stop().fadeOut();
    else
       $('#background').stop().fadeIn();
  }
});
```

No error message showing just fade out not happening on scrolling page.

Comment: When you expect fading? 250, 1250?

Comment: I expect it to happen at 250

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 250)
        $('#background').stop().fadeOut();
    else
        $('#background').stop().fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work for you.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 250) {
    $("#background").stop().fadeOut();
  } else {
    $("#background").stop().fadeIn();
  }
});
```

```css
.background-div {
  background: url("https://d2gg9evh47fn9z.cloudfront.net/800px_COLOURBOX25806764.jpg")no-repeat
    75%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:200vh">
  <div id="background" class="background-div">
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown">
      <a href="index.html">Home</a>
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
      <a href="contact-php.html">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div class="contact-title">
      <h2>Get in touch with us</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: it does seem to work well in codepen and here - unfortunately not on my website. I have tried in my local html page and also in netlify to see if would make any difference but no

Comment: works now thanks! just does not work offline or on Netlify? Guess I will have to install jquery to my machine to put it to work?

Comment: still doesn't work so unsure really why doesn't work if I open my local html file on chrome. Have tried to add the local jquery file but still same thing